# C++ Nested loops/Dynamic Array E

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

The programme I've written is supposed to take a number of rows from the user input and then display that many rows of asterisks, with one asterisk in the first row, two in the second, and so on.
It works but I have two problems:

1) There is always an additional symbol at the beginning of every line and I don't know where it originates. I've tried displaying the [0] value of the array but it doesn't seem to be coming from there.

2) While inputting some numbers (not all) of rows, the programme displays them with additional random symbols immediately after the rows. Is this a problem with the dynamic memory allocation?

Thank you for your help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
int number;
cin >> number;
int q = number + 1;
char dot = '.';
char asterisk = '*';
char * array1 = new char[q];

int n, m, s;
n = number;
for (n; n > 0; n--)
    {
        array1[n] = asterisk;

        for (m = n - 1; m > -1; m--)
            {
                array1[m] = dot;
            }

        cout << array1 << endl;
    }
delete [] array1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array indices start from `0`. So if you start with, say, `10` rows, the first iteration sets `array1[10]` to a * - but that is actually the 11th character in the string.

Comment: Your more serious problem is that your string isn't null terminated. You need to allocate space for one extra character and set it to 0.

Comment: You don't initialize the allocated memory so it may contain whatever and printing it may cause undefined behaviour since you don't terminate it with nul

Comment: I propose to use STL container wherever possible. Use std::string and std::vector instead of allocating manually. Is it just for learning? Even then it is better to learn the "correct" way.

Answer (score 0):

The char[] is not terminated with a NUL char so the << operator doesn't know when to stop writing. Try using cout.write() instead.